# How to index into 2d array with string indices

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, grep

So I have a couple questions as to the most efficient way to setup and use my data structures.

First, I have a 1D string array in the form `[header1 string1.1 string1.2 .. string1.n header2 string2.1 .. string2.n ...]`. I want to set up a 2d array where each `stringX.Y` has 4 integers associated with it.

e.g.

```
header1
string1.1 0 0 0 0
string2.1 0 0 0 0

header2
string2.1 0 0 0 0
...
```

1. What is the best way to set this up (initialized to 0) if I already have the 1D string array?
2. How can I index into the 2D array by string?

Then I need to grep multiple files `path1/foo* path2/foo*` and use a master `master_search_string` combined with the above string indices. I will then break this down into the 4 buckets depending on hardcoded strings I'm expecting (e.g. `foo bar baz other`)

My original (modified) kernel is as follows:

```
for item in $list;
do
    s1=`grep -P "bucket1:.*$item" $path | wc -l`
    s2=`grep -P "bucket2:.*$item" $path | wc -l`
    s3=`grep -P "bucket3:.*$item" $path | wc -l`
    s4=`grep -P "bucket4:.*$item" $path | wc -l`
    echo "$item $s1 $s2 $s3 $s4" >> $outFile
done
```

Comment: Everything depends not on efficiency but on what you want to *do* with your data once you have built it. Your original flat array of strings doesn't sound like a useful choice in the first place. Please describe your application and show some *real* data so that we can understand you better.

Comment: I already have the original flat array because I was doing this in a different way that was the easiest to code. I want to build it for run time now. Added the kernel of my original script to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going back to the original file and keeping the string lists separate (eg `string1.* string2.*` etc). These were hashes so I created an array of hash references. To change each value stored in the hash from a scalar to an array I did (modified for simplicity):

```
my %full_list;
@list = \(%string1, %string2, %string3);
foreach (0 .. $#list) {
    my $temp_list = $list[$_];
    foreach my $key (sort keys %$temp_list){
        delete $temp_list->{$key};
        $temp_list->{$key} = [0,0,0,0]; #this creates a list reference, but not sure if I am doing this the best way
        $full_list{$key} = $temp_list->{$key}; #creates a shallow copy so I can index the arrays with either the full_list by index
    }
}
```

The last line of code solves my second question. To index into the array we can do `$full_list{$key}[0]`.

***there could be typos in my code since it is a simplified version of what I actually did.*